# How to define phantoms for depth and height?

Tags: macros, tex-core

In the third "dangerous bend" on page 178 of of *The TeXbook* there's the following description of `\vphantom`:

> Even more useful than `\phantom` is `\vphantom`, which makes an invisible
>   box whose height and depth are the same as those of the corresponding
>   \phantom, but the width is zero.

In Appendix B (page 360)  one finds the definitions for `\vphantom`, `\hphantom` and `\phantom`:

```
\newif\ifv@ \newif\ifh@
\def\vphantom{\v@true\h@false\ph@nt}
\def\hphantom{\v@false\h@true\ph@nt}
\def\phantom{\v@true\h@true\ph@nt}
\def\ph@nt{\ifmmode\def\next{\mathpalette\mathph@nt}%
  \else\let\next=\makeph@nt\fi \next}
\def\makeph@nt#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\finph@nt}
\def\mathph@nt#1#2{\setbox0=\hbox{$\m@th#1{#2}$}\finph@nt}
\def\finph@nt{\setbox2=\null \ifv@ \ht2=\ht0 \dp2=\dp0 \fi
  \ifh@ \wd2=\wd0 \fi \box2 }
```

And here are the definitions in the LaTeX kernel (`ltmath.dtx`, page 256 of `source2e.pdf`):

```
\newif\ifv@
\newif\ifh@
\def\vphantom{\v@true\h@false\ph@nt}
\def\hphantom{\v@false\h@true\ph@nt}
\def\phantom{\v@true\h@true\ph@nt}
\def\ph@nt{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\mathpalette\expandafter\mathph@nt
  \else
    \expandafter\makeph@nt
  \fi}
\def\makeph@nt#1{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{\color@begingroup#1\color@endgroup}\finph@nt}
\def\mathph@nt#1#2{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1{#2}$}\finph@nt}
\def\finph@nt{%
  \setbox\tw@\null
  \ifv@ \ht\tw@\ht\z@ \dp\tw@\dp\z@\fi
  \ifh@ \wd\tw@\wd\z@\fi \box\tw@}
```

Since `\vphantom` preserves total height (=height+depth), I wonder why there's no depth-only and height-only phantoms? More precisely, how can the above definitions be extended to define `\dphantom` (for depth only) and `\htphantom` (for height only)? The former would produce an invisible box whose *depth* is the same as that of the corresponding `\phantom` but whose width and height are zero, and the latter would produce an invisible box whose *height* is the same as that of the corresponding `\phantom` but its width and depth are zero.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For example, the switch `\ifv@` can be split into two switches for the height and depth: `\ifv@ht@` and `\ifv@dp@`.

The the macros are changed in this way (unchanged macros are commented):

### plain TeX

```
% \newif\ifh@            
\newif\ifv@ht@ \newif\ifv@dp@
\def\vphantom {\v@ht@true \v@dp@true \h@false\ph@nt}
\def\hphantom {\v@ht@false\v@dp@false\h@true \ph@nt}
\def\htphantom{\v@ht@true \v@dp@false\h@false\ph@nt}  
\def\dpphantom{\v@ht@false\v@dp@true \h@false\ph@nt}  
\def\phantom  {\v@ht@true \v@dp@true \h@true \ph@nt}      
%\def\ph@nt{\ifmmode\def\next{\mathpalette\mathph@nt}%
%  \else\let\next=\makeph@nt\fi \next}
%\def\makeph@nt#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\finph@nt}
%\def\mathph@nt#1#2{\setbox0=\hbox{$\m@th#1{#2}$}\finph@nt}
\def\finph@nt{%
  \setbox2=\null
  \ifv@ht@ \ht2=\ht0 \fi
  \ifv@dp@ \dp2=\dp0 \fi  
  \ifh@ \wd2=\wd0 \fi   
  \box2 %
}

% Macro \test, which visualizes the bounding box
\def\test#1#2{%
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{%  
    \vrule  
    \vbox{%  
      \hrule 
      \vtop{%
        \hbox{#1{#2}}%
        \hrule
      }%
    }%
    \vrule
  }%
}

g \test\phantom{g} \test\hphantom{g} \test\vphantom{g}
\test\htphantom{g} \test\dpphantom{g}
\bye
```

> [image: Test result]

### LaTeX

LaTeX has inherited these macros from plain TeX. It has only changed `\makeph@nt` to add color support. But this command does not need to be changed. The following example redefines these macros for LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifv@ht@ \newif\ifv@dp@
\renewcommand*{\vphantom} {\v@ht@true \v@dp@true \h@false\ph@nt}
\renewcommand*{\hphantom} {\v@ht@false\v@dp@false\h@true \ph@nt}
\newcommand*  {\htphantom}{\v@ht@true \v@dp@false\h@false\ph@nt}
\newcommand*  {\dpphantom}{\v@ht@false\v@dp@true \h@false\ph@nt}
\renewcommand*{\phantom}  {\v@ht@true \v@dp@true \h@true \ph@nt}
\renewcommand*{\finph@nt}{%
  \setbox2=\null
  \ifv@ht@ \ht2=\ht0 \fi
  \ifv@dp@ \dp2=\dp0 \fi
  \ifh@ \wd2=\wd0 \fi
  \box2 %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  % Macro \test visualizes the bounding box
  \newcommand*{\test}[2]{%
    \begingroup
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
      \fbox{#1{#2}}%
    \endgroup
  }
  g \test\phantom{g} \test\hphantom{g} \test\vphantom{g}
  \test\htphantom{g} \test\dpphantom{g}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 17):

With `amsmath` you can define

```
\newcommand{\heightphantom}[1]{\vphantom{\smash[b]{#1}}
\newcommand{\depthphantom}[1]{\vphantom{\smash[t]{#1}}
```

Not as efficient as Heiko's, but shorter to define.

---

An `expl3` version, with a key-value interface. The `*`-version of the command doesn't force horizontal mode, if one really needs it.

The keys specify what dimensions are to be kept; specifying none means keeping all three (height, depth and width). Thus `\xphantom{g}` is mainly equivalent to `\phantom{g}` (apart from the automatic `\leavevmode`), while `\xphantom[width]{g}` and `\xphantom[totalheight]{g}` are equivalent to `\hphantom` and `\vphantom` respectively. Shorthands `\xhphantom` and `\xvphantom` are provided for these.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xphantom}{som}
 {% #2 is a list of key-value options, #3 is the text
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\leavevmode}
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \manual_phantom:nn { totalheight , width } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \manual_phantom:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xhphantom}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \xphantom*[width]{#2}
   }
   {
    \xphantom[width]{#2}
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xvphantom}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \xphantom*[totalheight]{#2}
   }
   {
    \xphantom[totalheight]{#2}
   }
 }

\keys_define:nn { manual/xphantom }
 {
  height .bool_set:N  = \l__manual_phantom_keepht_bool,
  depth  .bool_set:N  = \l__manual_phantom_keepdp_bool,
  width  .bool_set:N  = \l__manual_phantom_keepwd_bool,
  totalheight .code:n = 
    \bool_set_true:N \l__manual_phantom_keepht_bool
    \bool_set_true:N \l__manual_phantom_keepdp_bool,
  height .default:n = true,
  depth  .default:n = true,
  width  .default:n = true,
  totalheight .default:n = ,
 }

\box_new:N \l__manual_phantom_input_box
\box_new:N \l__manual_phantom_box

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_phantom:nn #1 #2
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { manual/xphantom } { #1 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__manual_phantom_input_box { #2 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__manual_phantom_box {}
  \bool_if:NT \l__manual_phantom_keepht_bool
   {
    \box_set_ht:Nn \l__manual_phantom_box { \box_ht:N \l__manual_phantom_input_box }
   }
  \bool_if:NT \l__manual_phantom_keepdp_bool
   {
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l__manual_phantom_box { \box_dp:N \l__manual_phantom_input_box }
   }
  \bool_if:NT \l__manual_phantom_keepwd_bool
   {
    \box_set_wd:Nn \l__manual_phantom_box { \box_wd:N \l__manual_phantom_input_box }
   }
  \box_use:N \l__manual_phantom_box
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \fbox{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

g
\test{\xphantom{g}}
\test{\xphantom[width]{g}}
\test{\xphantom[totalheight]{g}}
\test{\xphantom[height]{g}}
\test{\xphantom[depth]{g}}

g
\test{\xphantom[height,width]{g}}
\test{\xphantom[depth,width]{g}}

g
\test{\xhphantom{g}}
\test{\xvphantom{g}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A version also implementing math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xphantom}{som}
 {% #2 is a list of key-value options, #3 is the text
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{ \mode_if_math:F { \leavevmode } }
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \manual_phantom:nn { totalheight , width } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \manual_phantom:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xhphantom}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \xphantom*[width]{#2}
   }
   {
    \xphantom[width]{#2}
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xvphantom}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \xphantom*[totalheight]{#2}
   }
   {
    \xphantom[totalheight]{#2}
   }
 }

\keys_define:nn { manual/xphantom }
 {
  height .bool_set:N  = \l__manual_phantom_keepht_bool,
  depth  .bool_set:N  = \l__manual_phantom_keepdp_bool,
  width  .bool_set:N  = \l__manual_phantom_keepwd_bool,
  totalheight .code:n = 
    \bool_set_true:N \l__manual_phantom_keepht_bool
    \bool_set_true:N \l__manual_phantom_keepdp_bool,
  height .default:n = true,
  depth  .default:n = true,
  width  .default:n = true,
  totalheight .default:n = ,
 }

\box_new:N \l__manual_phantom_input_box
\box_new:N \l__manual_phantom_box

\cs_new_protected:Npn \manual_phantom:nn #1 #2
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { manual/xphantom } { #1 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__manual_phantom_box {}
  \mode_if_math:TF
    {
     \__manual_phantom_math:n { #2 }
    }
    {
     \hbox_set:Nn \l__manual_phantom_input_box { #2 }
     \__manual_phantom_set:
    }
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__manual_phantom_set:
 {
  \bool_if:NT \l__manual_phantom_keepht_bool
   {
    \box_set_ht:Nn \l__manual_phantom_box { \box_ht:N \l__manual_phantom_input_box }
   }
  \bool_if:NT \l__manual_phantom_keepdp_bool
   {
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l__manual_phantom_box { \box_dp:N \l__manual_phantom_input_box }
   }
  \bool_if:NT \l__manual_phantom_keepwd_bool
   {
    \box_set_wd:Nn \l__manual_phantom_box { \box_wd:N \l__manual_phantom_input_box }
   }
  \box_use:N \l__manual_phantom_box
 }

% Now math mode; there's currently no syntactic sugar for \mathpalette
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__manual_phantom_math:n #1
 {
  \mathpalette \__manual_make_phantom_math:nn { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__manual_make_phantom_math:nn #1 #2
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__manual_phantom_input_box { $ #1 {#2} \mathsurround=0pt $ }
  \__manual_phantom_set:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \fbox{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

g
\test{\xphantom{g}}
\test{\xphantom[width]{g}}
\test{\xphantom[totalheight]{g}}
\test{\xphantom[height]{g}}
\test{\xphantom[depth]{g}}

g
\test{\xphantom[height,width]{g}}
\test{\xphantom[depth,width]{g}}

g
\test{\xhphantom{g}}
\test{\xvphantom{g}}

$\displaystyle\sum$
\test{$\displaystyle\xphantom{\sum}$}
\test{$\displaystyle\xvphantom{\sum}$}
\test{$\displaystyle\xhphantom{\sum}$}
\test{$\displaystyle\xphantom[height]{\sum}$}
\test{$\displaystyle\xphantom[depth]{\sum}$}
\test{$\displaystyle\xphantom[height,width]{\sum}$}
\test{$\displaystyle\xphantom[depth,width]{\sum}$}

$\textstyle\sum$
\test{$\textstyle\xphantom{\sum}$}
\test{$\textstyle\xvphantom{\sum}$}
\test{$\textstyle\xhphantom{\sum}$}

$\scriptstyle\sum$
\test{$\scriptstyle\xphantom{\sum}$}
\test{$\scriptstyle\xvphantom{\sum}$}
\test{$\scriptstyle\xhphantom{\sum}$}

$\scriptscriptstyle\sum$
\test{$\scriptscriptstyle\xphantom{\sum}$}
\test{$\scriptscriptstyle\xvphantom{\sum}$}
\test{$\scriptscriptstyle\xhphantom{\sum}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't extend the existing `\vphantom` definition, but provides an alternative.  It works in text mode as well as all styles of math mode.
EDITED to remove package dependence on `scalerel`, but the `\thisstyle` and `\savedstyle` definitions that remain largely mimic those from the package (`\ThisStyle` and `\SavedStyle`).  EDITED to add `\wdphantom`, `\htwdphantom`, and `\dpwdphantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@mstyleD{\displaystyle}
\def\@mstyleT{\textstyle}
\def\@mstyleS{\scriptstyle}
\def\@mstyles{\scriptscriptstyle}
\let\@mstyleX\relax
\def\savedstyle{\csname @mstyle\m@switch\endcsname}
%
\def\thisstyle#1{%
  \ifmmode\mathchoice%
      {\edef\m@switch{D}#1}{\edef\m@switch{T}#1}{\edef\m@switch{S}#1}{\edef\m@switch{s}#1}%
  \else\edef\m@switch{X}#1\fi%
}
\makeatother
\def\preservebox#1{\thisstyle{\setbox0=\hbox{\savedstyle#1}}}
\def\htphantom#1{\preservebox{#1}\rule{0pt}{\ht0}}
\def\dpphantom#1{\preservebox{#1}\rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dp0}}
\def\wdphantom#1{\preservebox{#1}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}
\def\htwdphantom#1{\preservebox{#1}\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}
\def\dpwdphantom#1{\preservebox{#1}\rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dp0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}
\def\test#1{#1 \fbox{\phantom{#1}} \fbox{\vphantom{#1}} 
  \fbox{\wdphantom{#1}} \fbox{\htphantom{#1}} \fbox{\dpphantom{#1}}
    \fbox{\htwdphantom{#1}} \fbox{\dpwdphantom{#1}} \par}
\fboxsep=0pt\relax\fboxrule=.2pt
\begin{document}
\test{g}\test{$g$}\test{$\scriptscriptstyle g$}\test{\Large g}
\test{$\sum_{i=1}^N$}
\test{$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N$}
\end{document}
```

[image]